# Login to Host system from vm-ware guest system using Python

Tags: python, authentication, copy-paste, vmware-player

I have a situation, I want to copy some files from host system (which is win7) to guest system (vm-ware image of winXP). For that I have created a python script, but my script only copies files and fails whenever host system's credentials are changed (particularly Password). I'm using "Remember me" option when dialog for credentials is prompted.

But I was wondering is there any particular way to login to host system without prompted for credentials. As I'm running vmware inside host which means I already have logged into it, so why it is necessary for password?

If that don't do, say because of any security reasons or any thing, is there any other way to login from python script to host system.

Also, I want to improve my script little bit, currently I'm using my host system's IP-Address to have access to those particular folders. So is there any alternative way other than IP-address because my machine's IP address also changes randomly anytime (I'm stunned when this happens. I don't know the reason. Please help me to make this constant). Can I use computer's Name instead of IP?

I want to do everything automatically so don't want to use 'Shared Folder' option.

Any answer or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.